# ng-xi18n throws exception for using full path in templateUrl

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, angular-compiler-cli

I have components where I use full path in `templateUrl`

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/components/controls/checkbox/checkbox.html'
})
```

I am aware that I can use `moduleId: module.id`, but I want to keep full path to html file for my deployment purpose. When I run ng-xi18n, I am getting an error:

```
    Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: 
C:/Users/TestUser/Source/Workspaces/MyApp/src/app/
components/controls/checkbox/app/components/controls/checkbox/checkbox.html
```

Is there a way to solve this issue without using `moduleId: module.id`? 
Thanks